# draw_geometries function in open3d crashes the program with following error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Tags: python, open3d

I am trying to read a simple .pcd point cloud and visualize it with open3d. The code crashes with the error of : Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I am using windows 10, python 3.7.6, open3d version 0.7.0

Comment: Please provide [minimal exapmple](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).